# Where can I find a guide to the inner workings of Internet Explorer's Trident engine?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, layout-engine

Just as the title says. As i went through different explanations for choices made about the stylesheets of HTML pages, the masters sometimes seem to know how this layout engine seems to work in IE6, IE7 or IE8. I haven't found a good resource about Trident yet, maybe you guys can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a guide to the inner workings of Trident, since the only people who have seen the code are prevented from disclosing it by NDA.  I have seen it, and I know a lot about how it works, and I can assure you that any reference other than the code won't help you anyway.  If you have specific questions, you should feel free to ask your specific questions.

Comment: Thank you. It's sad though that things have to be like this.

Comment: I have a question.. Trident with IE8 have some performance issues with jquery. Is there any way to upgrade the rendering engine from v4 to 5 without upgrading to IE9?

Comment: The rendering engine (mshtml.dll) is separate from the script engine (jscript.dll).  Despite living in different DLLs, there are still fairly tight couplings between all of the IE DLLs in that IE9 mshtml.dll expects IE9 ieframe.dll and IE9 jscript.dll, etc.  Mixing and matching will violate interface contracts and other implicit assumptions and things just won't work.